# Firefox extension localStorage events

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, local-storage, firefox4

I am making a Firefox extension to determine when a "storage" event is fired from the localStorage.

In Firefox 3, I have this line to bind the storage event in the window to a function in the extension.

`$(doc, doc).bind('storage', on_store());`

This works in Firefox 3.  However, this does not seem to get the event when it is tried in Firefox 4.

Comment: Did you try using a non-JQuery method like `addEventListener`, just to see if maybe Firefox 4 changed something that makes it harder to use JQuery in an extension?

Comment: Why `on_store()` and not `on_store`? Does `on_store()` return a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event) seems to suggest the `storage` event will fire on the window (so `$(window).bind('storage', on_store)` is the correct way to bind it).